# Are quasiaffine subsets of $\mathbb{A}_F^n$ always necessarily open or closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

Something I was wondering about lately, suppose $\mathbb{A}_F^n$ is affine space over a field $F$ which is algebraically closed. When I say a quasi-affine set, I mean a set that is locally closed, so can be written as $Z_1\setminus Z_2$, where $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are closed in $\mathbb{A}^n_F$.

Are the quasiaffine subsets $Z\subseteq\mathbb{A}_F^n$ always either open or closed, or is it possible to have some such subset that is neither?

If not, are there known dimensions $n$ for which all quasiaffine $Z\subseteq\mathbb{A}_F^n$ must be either closed or open?

Comment: A subset has no scheme structure. What do you mean by qs-affine subset? Do you mean locally closed subschemes?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what your definition is for "quasiaffine subset", but consider an example like $\{(x,0)\mid x\neq 0\} \subset \mathbb{A}^2$.  The former can be identified with $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{0\}$, which is quasi-affine (in fact, it's even affine).  But it's not open or closed in $\mathbb{A}^2$.

Definitions really matter here, but hopefully this example resolves some of your confusion.

Comment: Thanks Slade, sorry I didn't include the definition the first time around. This answer definitely helps.